# Automatically remove numbers and alphanumeric words except for those containing "ème"

Tags: python-3.x, sed

Using sed, or another program that I can run on a directory of txt files, how can I remove pure numbers as well as combinations of numbers and letters from a file, *except* those that are part of French cardinal numbers (e.g. 2ème).

For instance, if a text file contained

```
12h03 11:00 27.8.16 23 3ème bonjour
```

then I only want to retain

```
3ème bonjour
```

**Edit:** *bonjour* is retained because no numbers occur in it. *3ème* is retained because it ends in *ème* (cardinal number). The other tokens are removed because they contain numbers but aren't cardinal numbers.

Comment: What is the actual rule? You say you only want words that include 'ème' and then you include bonjour in your example as something to keep. What part of the rule set allowed 'bonjour' to be included in the output?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear: Words should be removed if a number occurs in them, unless it ends on 'ème'.

Comment: So this line "then I only want to retain '3ème bonjour'." should read "then I only want to retain '3èmer'." Is that right?

Comment: No, 'bonjour' doesn't contain any numbers, so it shouldn't be removed.

Comment: How much do you care about `sed`? Would a Python solution be acceptable given "or another program that I can run on a directory of txt files"?

Answer (score 0):

jwpfox: I've never used Python before, but I'd be willing to use it.

In the meantime, I've written a pig ugly `R` script that seems to do the trick well enough for my purposes. I'll share it here.

```
# Sample text
text <- "Le 8 septembre à 11h30, Jean voyait les 2 filles pour la 3ème fois."

# Split up by space
splittext <- unlist(strsplit(text, 
                             split = " "))

# Retain words containing no numbers, or that contain 'ème' or punctuation.
selecttext <- splittext[!(grepl("\\d", splittext)) | 
                        grepl("ème", splittext) |
                        grepl("[[:punct:]]", splittext)]

# If a word contains both numbers and punctuation, retain only the punctuation
selecttext[grepl("\\d", selecttext) & grepl("[[:punct:]]", selecttext)] <- stringr::str_sub(selecttext[grepl("\\d", selecttext) & grepl("[[:punct:]]", selecttext)], start=-1, end =-1)

# Recombine
text2 <- paste(selecttext, collapse = " ")


> text2
[1] "Le septembre à , Jean voyait les filles pour la 3ème fois."
```

It should then be a matter of reading in all files in the directory, running them through the lines above, and overwriting the source files.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are open to a Python answer here is one in Python3.

Provide the path to the root directory of the tree you want to work on in the `filepath` variable and this will walk all the files in the tree below that directory and apply the rule you supplied.

Note that the rule you seem to be applying in your `R` code seems to be different to the rule you set out in your question.

```
import os
import re

filepath = 'testfiles'
for(path, dirs, files) in os.walk(filepath):
    searchpattern = re.compile('[0-9]')
    for filename in files:
        curfilepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        with open(curfilepath, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
            cleanlines = []
            for line in infile:
                cleanline = ''
                words = line.split(' ')
                for word in words:
                    if 'ème' in word:
                        cleanline += word + ' '
                    if searchpattern.search(word) is None:
                        cleanline += word + ' '
                cleanline = cleanline.strip()
                if len(cleanline) > 0:
                    cleanlines.append(cleanline)

        with open(curfilepath, mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            for line in cleanlines:
                outfile.write(line + '\n')
```